# How to access the list of installed languages

Tags: java, android

I am working on an App which is supposed to use TTS to read text in different languages. Instead of providing the user a list off all available languages (which I personally find very cumbersome to deal with), I would like him to see only the languages currently installed on his phone. In other words, my app should not install new languages, it should only access the languages already installed on the phone and switch between them.

Here is my example with system/settings/languages&input/language preferences: [image: phone language preferences].

With Locale.getDefault() I only get the default language (in my case: en_US), with getLocales I get all types of Locales, so how can I get a list of the 3 installed languages: en_US, de_DE, es_ES, preferably in an array of type Locale.

I am kind of feeling stuck here, so any help is very much appreciated :-).

Answer (score 3):

With API-Level 24 the following solution is possible:

LocaleList.getDefault() : provides a list off the currently installed Locales.

```
        String strLocales = "";
        LocaleList myLocales = LocaleList.getDefault();
        for (int i = 0; i<myLocales.size(); i++) {
            strLocales = stringLocales + "\n" + myLocales.get(i).getDisplayLanguage();
            strLocales = stringLocales + " / " + myLocales.get(i).getDisplayCountry();
        }
```

The result (strLocales) is:

- English / United States
- Spanish / Spain
- German / Germany

This is exactly what I was looking for. Unfortunately; I still do not know, how to resolve this for pre-24 version, and would appreciate any help.

Comment: required API 24 and higher, do you have any solution for lower APIs?